# How to hide My results tab for the User using Quiz module in Drupal 7

Tags: quiz

It looks so silly to ask these questions but I'm beginner in drupal. I need a help on implementing the modules. I'm trying to build a portal using Quiz Module wherein I need to hide a tab for the user but should be visible to administrator.

Is it possible to hide the My results tab in drupal 7? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tab Tamer](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module.

Project page says:

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering,
> hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs.

For more information go through the module documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **modules->quiz core module** and in `configuration/permission` uncheck **view own result**. That is it. If you want to re-enable it, just check it